# pass iframe src parameters to the code inside

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with parameters inside the src url like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.form-page.com?suppressRedirect=1&A=1841" width="271px" height="295px" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" style="position: absolute;left: 0;z-index: 1000;padding-left: 5px;"></iframe>
```

I need to get the parameters inside of the "**form-page**"

is there a way to do this in php or jquery?

Comment: The iFrame is just like the frame. It opens a whole new webpage without addressbar and all. It behaves in same was as if opened in a new tab. So you can access all parameters through `$_GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in php check the $_GET array

```
$_GET['suppressRedirect'];
$_GET['A'];
```

the values should be 1 and 1841 respectively

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameters via the querystring as you would any normal request.

```
$_GET['suppressRedirect']; // = 1
$_GET['A']; // = 1841
```

Answer (score 0):

On your index.php you can grab values of those parameters like:

```
$suppressRedirect = $_GET['suppressRedirect'];
$A = $_GET['A'];
// use these two variables as you like now
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing all parameters through URL in the usual way, ie, via the $_GET variable!
All parameters are stored in the superglobal variable (array type) $_GET.

In your page:

```
http://www.form-page.com?suppressRedirect=1&A=1841
```

It is supposed that your are receiving those parameters in the  index.php file as `$_GET['A']` and `$_GET['suppressRedirect']`.

OBS: PHP variables are case-sensitive: `$_GET['A']` is distinct to `$_GET['a']`